# Error: You cannot call webbrowser methods until it is in the visual tree

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, admob

I started using a Google AdMob control in WP7 application and getting an exception thrown. I believe the control uses a webbrowser inside it.  I am getting this following error on my page now.  Any suggestions on how to resolve this.

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
  Message=You cannot call WebBrowser methods until it is in the visual tree.
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.WebBrowserDisconnected.NavigateToString(String pszHtml)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.WebBrowser.NavigateToString(String html)
   at Google.AdMob.Ads.WindowsPhone7.WPF.DisplayAdBase.<.ctor>b__7(Object , RoutedEventArgs )
   at System.Windows.CoreInvokeHandler.InvokeEventHandler(Int32 typeIndex, Delegate handlerDelegate, Object sender, Object args)
   at MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex, String eventName)
```

I am using WP7 Navigation recipe in the app -
http://create.msdn.com/en-us/education/catalog/article/nln-serv-wp7

I believe Google AdMob control is throwing the error during the back navigation of the page stack.  so, if you navigate to page 1, page 2 (has Google AdMob control), page 3 and then press a home button to come back to page 1, the error gets thrown by page 2 during the back navigation.

I don't know how to resolve this as the webbrowser control is within the google ad control.  Anyone else running into this issue?

Comment: Is your Google AdMob control made for WP7? WebBrowser support is different on desktop Silverlight vs WP7 Silverlight.

Comment: How are you adding the control to the page?

Comment: I have updated the question with some information at the bottom about why the exception may be getting raised.

Answer (score 3):

a quick solution:
on your app.xaml.cs is this event... 
paste the exception of ADMOB...

```
// Code to execute on Unhandled Exceptions
private void Application_UnhandledException(object sender, ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
    {
        // An unhandled exception has occurred; break into the debugger
        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
    }

    else
    {
        //this is the ADMOB exception
        if (e.ExceptionObject.Message == "You cannot call WebBrowser methods until it is in the visual tree.")
            e.Handled = true;

        else
             MessageBox.Show(e.ExceptionObject.Message, "007", MessageBoxButton.OK);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. This seems like a hack as well.  I am surprised Google hasn't fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this as well, but in my own PhoneApplicationPage code.

Looks like the control constructor is trying to call WebBrowser.NavigateToString, but you can tell by the exception that this is not allowed.    It's obvious no one's actually tested this code.

I was doing something similar in a Page constructor, and the way I fixed it was for the Page to listen for the WebBrowser.Loaded event, then call WebBrowser.Navigate/NavigateToString.

If you have access to the control's source code, try doing that - in the constructor,

1. save the html content to a local variable
2. register a WebBrowser.Loaded event handler
3. in the event handler, pass the html content to WebBrowser.NavigateToString